# Thin white lines being added when cropping an image (Objective-C OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, crop, nsimage

I am cutting up a large image and saving it into many different images. I first implemented this in `iOS` and it is working fine, but when I try and port the code to `OSX`, a thin white line (1 pixel) appears on the top and right of the image. The line is not pure white, or solid (see sample below).

Here is the `iOS` code to make one sub-image, that works like a champ:

```
-(void)testMethod:(int)page forRect:(CGRect)rect{
    NSString *filePath = @"imageName";

    NSData *data = [HeavyResourceManager dataForPath:filePath];//this just gets the image as NSData
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);//crop in the rect

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0 orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(result, 1.0) writeToFile:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent::@"output.jpg"] atomically:YES];
}
```

Here is the ported code in `OSX` that causes the white lines to be added:

```
NSImage *source = [[[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] autorelease];
//init the image
NSImage *target = [[[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:panelRect.size] autorelease];
//start drawing
[target lockFocus];
[source drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,panelRect.size.width,panelRect.size.height)
          fromRect:NSMakeRect(panelRect.origin.x , source.size.height - panelRect.origin.y - panelRect.size.height, panelRect.size.width, panelRect.size.height)
         operation:NSCompositeCopy
          fraction:1.0];
[target unlockFocus];

//create a NSBitmapImageRep
NSBitmapImageRep *bmpImageRep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[target TIFFRepresentation]] autorelease];
//write to tiff
[[target TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:@"outputImage.tiff" atomically:NO];
[target addRepresentation:bmpImageRep];     
NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];

//get the data from the representation
NSData *data = [bmpImageRep representationUsingType: NSJPEGFileType
                                             properties: imageProps];

//write the data to a file
[data writeToFile: @"outputImage.jpg" atomically:NO];

data = [bmpImageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: imageProps];

//write the data to png
[data writeToFile: @"outputImage.png" atomically:NO];
```

The above code saves the image to three different formats to check if the problem was not in the save process of a specific format. It does not seem to be because all the formats have the same problem.

Here is a blown up (4x) version of top right hand corner of the images:

[image: OSX, note the white line top and left]

(OSX, note the white line top and left. It looks like a blur here, because the image is blown up)

[image: iOS, note no white lines]

(iOS, note there are no white lines)

If someone could tell me why this might be happening, I would be very happy. Perhaps it has something to do with the quality difference (the OSX version seems lower quality - though you can't notice)? Perhaps there is a completely different way to do this?

For reference, here is the unscaled osx image:

[image: OSX Image original]

---

*Update*: Thanks to [Daij-Djan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620526/377384), I was able to stop the `drawInRect` method from antialiasing:

```
    //start drawing on target
    [target lockFocus];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
            setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationNone];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias:NO];

    //draw the portion of the source image on target image
    [source drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,panelRect.size.width,panelRect.size.height)
              fromRect:NSMakeRect(panelRect.origin.x , source.size.height - panelRect.origin.y - panelRect.size.height, panelRect.size.width, panelRect.size.height)
             operation:NSCompositeDestinationAtop
              fraction:1.0];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    //end drawing
    [target unlockFocus];
```

---

*Update*: Changed 'Interpolation' to `NSImageInterpolationNone`, as this gives a better representation. The high interpolation makes minor adjustments, which is noticeable when zooming in on text. Removing interpolation stops pixels from jumping around, but still, there is a little difference in the color (164 to 155 for a grey color). Would be great to be able to just cut up an image like I can in iOS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like antialiasing... you gotta round the float values you calculate when cutting/scaling the image.

use froundf() on the float values

Comment: ++++1 - it was the antialiasing! Thanks!

Comment: Note: I just stopped doing antialiasing (see edit in question above).